# Button on CustomCellRenderer only displays label

Tags: actionscript-3, cellrenderer, tilelist

I am implementing my own CustomCellRenderer for a TileList. It has it's own button that I add, but the button won't display anything except the label text. Here is a code snippet:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends ImageCell implements ICellRenderer
{               
        private var m_listData:ListData;
        private var m_data:Object;
        private var m_buyButton:Button;

        public function CustomCellRenderer ()
        {
            m_buyButton = new Button();
            m_buyButton.width = 25;
            m_buyButton.height = 50;
            m_buyButton.x = 40;
            m_buyButton.y = 50;
            m_buyButton.textField.text = "BUY";
            m_buyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnPurchaseClick);
            addChild(m_buyButton);
        }

    private function OnPurchaseClick(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("PurchaseClick");
    }

    public override function set data(a_data:Object):void
    {
        label = "";
        m_data = a_data;
    }

    public override function get data():Object
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    public override function set listData(a_listdata:ListData):void
    {
        m_listData = a_listdata;
    }

    public override function get listData():ListData
    {
        return m_listData;
    }
}
```

The "BUY" label shows up, so the button isn't offscreen and is actually a child of the cell, but for some reason the button skin isn't showing up and it won't take any mouse clicks. I have tried setting different upskins for the button and nothing changes. I am at a loss here, anyone have an idea as to what might be happening?

Comment: Looks like setting mouseChildren = true for the cell effects this problem, it's not quite working right but it has having a mouse over state show now.

Comment: The new problem is that the button skin doesn't show up until it is moused over and then after that it stays, even if mouse is moved away. Pretty strange. Any ideas?